# mod_rewrite cookies lost

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, cookies, xampp, localhost

I have url:

```
http://localhost/subdir/subdir/view_project.php?pid=1
```

rewriten url:

```
http://localhost/project/3-dasda
```

and mod rewrite rule

```
RewriteBase /subdir/subdir/
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)(.*)$ view_project.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

And this is working okay, except when i try to access my cookies on http://localhost/project/3-dasda only cookie that i have is "PHPSESSID". If i access 'http://localhost/subdir/subdir/view_project.php?pid=1' all cookies are there. Session is there in both cases. I cant figure out what is happening?

Comment: Ensure that the cookie path is set to `/` and not something more restrictive, which could result in the missing cookie behavior you describe

Comment: already done that: setcookie('string',$string,0,'/');

Comment: I have tried the same thing on an webserver (godaddy hosting), and its working normally. Same file, same setup. I cant figure out wth is happening?